# When to use Serializer's create() and ModelViewset's perform_create()

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I want to clarify the given documentation of Django-rest-framework regarding the creation of a model object. So far I have found that there are 3 approaches on how to handle such events.

1. The Serializer's `create()` method. Here is the [documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#saving-instances)

   ```
   class CommentSerializer(serializers.Serializer):

       def create(self, validated_data):
           return Comment.objects.create(**validated_data)
   ```
2. The ModelViewset `create()` method. [Documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset)

   ```
   class AccountViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

       queryset = Account.objects.all()
       serializer_class = AccountSerializer
       permission_classes = [IsAccountAdminOrReadOnly]
   ```
3. The ModelViewset `perform_create()` method. [Documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/6-viewsets-and-routers/#refactoring-to-use-viewsets)

   ```
   class SnippetViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

       def perform_create(self, serializer):
           serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)
   ```

These three approaches are important depending on your application environment.
But when do we need to use each `create() / perform_create()` function? On the other hand, I found some accounts that two create methods were called for a single post request the `ModelViewSet`'s `create()` and serializer's `create()`.

Answer (score 191, accepted):

1. You would use `create(self, validated_data)` to add any extra details into the object before saving AND "prod" values into each model field just like `**validated_data` does. Ideally speaking, you want to do this form of "prodding" only in ONE location so the `create` method in your `CommentSerializer` is the best place. On top of this, you might want to also call external apis to create user accounts on their side just before saving your accounts into your own database. You should use this `create` function in conjunction with`ModelViewSet`. Always think - "Thin views, Thick serializers".

   Example:

   ```
   def create(self, validated_data):
       email = validated_data.get("email", None)
       validated.pop("email") 
       # Now you have a clean valid email string 
       # You might want to call an external API or modify another table
       # (eg. keep track of number of accounts registered.) or even
       # make changes to the email format.

       # Once you are done, create the instance with the validated data
       return models.YourModel.objects.create(email=email, **validated_data)
   ```
2. The `create(self, request, *args, **kwargs)` function in the `ModelViewSet` is defined in the `CreateModelMixin` class which is the parent of `ModelViewSet`. `CreateModelMixin`'s main functions are these:

   ```
   from rest_framework import status
   from rest_framework.response import Response


   def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
       serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
       self.perform_create(serializer)
       headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
       return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)

   def perform_create(self, serializer):
       serializer.save()
   ```

   As you can see, the above `create` function takes care of calling validation on your serializer and producing the correct response. The beauty behind this, is that you can now isolate your application logic and NOT concern yourself about the mundane and repetitive validation calls and handling response output :). This works quite well in conjuction with the `create(self, validated_data)` found in the serializer (where your specific application logic might reside).
3. Now you might ask, why do we have a separate `perform_create(self, serializer)` function with just one line of code!?!? Well, the main reason behind this is to allow customizeability when calling the `save` function. You might want to supply extra data before calling `save` **(like `serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)`** and if we didn't have `perform_create(self, serializer)`, you would have to override the `create(self, request, *args, **kwargs)` and that just defeats the purpose of having mixins doing the heavy and boring work.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your sharing your knowledge! About the `create(self, validated_data)` in the serializer, it means that it focuses on data validation logic? and more over it can help return the given serializer's data back to the response right?

Comment: No so at this point, you already have passed all your validation. I am talking about how you might want to customize the validated data just before it is saved into a database. I will make an example in my answer.

Comment: No worries - just added an example to give more context.

Comment: Then this code `return models.YourModel.objects.create(email=email, **validated_data)` will save the data from database right?

Comment: Yeah that is the final line that will save your object into the database

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130370/discussion-between-shift-n-tab-and-apoorv-kansal).

Comment: i have another question again because there is some approach which calls the `objects.create` both found in the `serializer` and `modelviewset`. here is an example:
`class AccountSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        def create(self, validated_data):
            return Account.objects.create(**validated_data)`
And
 `class AccountViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
        def create(self, request):
            serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
            if serializer.is_valid():
            Account.objects.create_user(**serializer.validated_data)`

Comment: I could interpret this one which creates double account but when tested it's only creates a single instance at all. Which one is called first? i am very confused at this.

Comment: So the `create` function in the serializer itself is **only** called when you do `serializer.save()`. In your `create(self, request)` function inside (`AccountViewSet`), you are not calling `serializer.save()` at all and therefore, the only instance creation is happening with this call: `Account.objects.create_user(**serializer.validated_data)`.

Comment: Is there `create()` and `perform_create()` has execute order?

Comment: @qg_java一坨子给你中疼 it depends on the situation, since perform_create can also be called in another definition (def:) such as update, delete, patch etc.. it means there is no execution order or precedence and it heavily relying on your own logic.

Comment: what about validation of fields? Suppose I have two numbers/fields and I want to check that one is less than the other.. where would you put all that field validation logic? in the view?
What about the full_clean method of the model? (So it can be used by the api and admin for example

Comment: Hi is it possible to do a get_or_create when performing the perform_create? Or is there another recommendation?

Comment: Thank you for a detailed explanation! But what do you mean by `"prod" values into model field`?

Answer (score 10):

While Apoorv's answer is correct and very detailed, here's a quick answer:

- Override `perform_create()` when you want to change the "behind-the-scenes" behavior of how your object is created. For example, performing some extra actions before or after the object is created.
- Override `create()` when you want to modify the response. For example, if you want to re-structure the response, add extra data, extra headers, etc.

Comment: Which create() method? The one that belongs to serializer or to ModelViewSet?