# Django change value before save in ModelViewSet

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am new to Django (and the REST framework) but I am struggling to update a value before save. Right now I am using a simple ModelViewSet to update a record. Everything works, but the value doesnt get updated if I create an item in de admin site.

Code of the view is as follows:

```
class OauthProviderViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = OauthProvider.objects.all()
    serializer_class = OauthProviderSerializer 
    authentication_classes = [SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [IsAdminUser]

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        changed_credentials = "test" + self.request.credentials
        serializer.save(credentials=changed_credentials)
```

I just want to pre-pend the word test to the credentials field.

EDIT: a post was suggested that explained the difference between the serializer's create and the model's create function. Funny thing is that 1. I dont understand the difference, but 2. Both of them didnt work.

EDIT2: Tried in the serializer with something I found, again everything works flawlessly but my snippet isnt executed:

```
class OauthProviderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = OauthProvider
        #fields = ['id', 'title', 'author']
        fields = "__all__"

    def create(self, instance, validated_data):
        validated_data['credentials'] = "test" + validated_data['credentials']
        return super(OauthProviderSerializer, self).create(validated_data)
```

EDIT3: I found the issue (partly). I was using the admin screen to create the values but that functionality doesnt use views or serializers. If I use the normal POST method my code gets executed.

Am I right that for this functionality it is best to update the ModelViewSet's perform_create method? According to this url: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2019/04/07/how-to-save-extra-data-to-a-django-rest-framework-serializer.html

Comment: *"update a value before save"*... Why are you not doing things in the serializer?

Comment: tell me how and I will do :) like I said, I am new

Comment: Ref DRF  doc: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#saving-instances

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When to use Serializer's create() and ModelViewset's create() perform\_create()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41094013/when-to-use-serializers-create-and-modelviewsets-create-perform-create)

Comment: I already found both links but I am so new to django that this dazzles me. I am sorry. Can you provide a snippet?

Comment: In the following url they are using my snippet: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2019/04/07/how-to-save-extra-data-to-a-django-rest-framework-serializer.html

Answer (score -1):

Each time you create a new model in the models.py file, you have to import that

model in the admin.py file, and apply the register method to it.

In your admin.py you import all your models. Like this:

from .models import * #Which means from the file models.py import all models.

admin.site.register(OauthProviderViewSet) #Then apply the register method.

Then you will be able to see the OauthProviderViewSet model in your admin.py file.

If you have already did this, and you can see the your model in the admin page,

then each time you create your items from the admin page you have to save them in

order for Django to update the database.

If you want to update your item from a form (in a template => html file that is

rendered by a function from the views.py file) and it is not working then something is wrong with your

views.py file.  It may mean your data are not save at all in the database.

Comment: Is this an answer to my question? The admin site works fine. I am just trying to update a value before saving