# What is different between update() method of Serializers class and UpdateAPIView?

Tags: django-rest-framework

I'm new to Django rest framework and I recently found that both serializers.Serializer and UpdateAPIView class have update().  UpdateAPIView class also have perform_update() method too.

My question is what different between 3 those method and what is the relation between them. Like when a person calls an API to update an instance. Which order of 3 methods will be called?

Comment: `perform_update()` will call/trigger the `update()` method of your serializer.

Comment: what about the update() method of APIView? and I wonder when the validation process for user's data happens? Is it happen in the update() method of APIView?

Comment: This should answer your question (just replace create with update) : https://stackoverflow.com/a/41094241/13964753

Comment: thanks, it exactly the same as my question