# Get image file and fields in Django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to upload image via django restframe work and return a custom response
**views.py**

```
class Imageuploadviewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
   queryset = UploadModel.objects.all()
   serializer_class = UploadSerializer
   def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    instance = self.get_object()
    serializer = self.get_serializer(instance)

    return Response({'something': 'serializer'})
   def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return Response({'Model': 'Skin Disease Diagnosis'})
```

**models.py**

```
class UploadModel(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    image=models.ImageField('images/')
```

**urls.py**

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'UploadModel', views.Imageuploadviewset)

urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.home,name='home'),
    path('api/', include(router.urls)),
]
```

**Serializer.py**

```
class UploadSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model=UploadModel
        fields='__all__'
```

Query is that how to play with `name` and `image` upload, run some functions on them and return a response. I am not sure how to get those.

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41094013/when-to-use-serializers-create-and-modelviewsets-create-perform-create

Comment: Have you tried Pillow?

Comment: There is no issue in uploading, issue is that I am unable to handle image at backend code

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `retrieve` and `list` i need the `create` function

```
def create(self, request):
      img=request.FILES['image']
      user=request.POST['name']
      pred=somefunction(ai,img)
      return Response({'user':user,'prediction':pred})
```