# Create model instance only if its user id field is equal to the logged-in user's id

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

In a django rest framework app, there's a TextViewSet. The Text object structure is as follows:

```
{
    text: text_value,
    author: author_id
}
```

When creating a new Text instance, I want to check if the supplied author_id equals the currently logged-in user's id.

I've read this question: [When to use Serializer's create() and ModelViewset's perform_create()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41094013/when-to-use-serializers-create-and-modelviewsets-perform-create), but still can't decide whether to override Serializer's create(), ModelViewset's create() or perform_create() methods. What's the right method to override?

UPD:

**models.py**:

```
class Text(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**serializers.py:**

```
class TextSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Text
        fields = ['author', 'text']
```

The question is in which of these methods should one perform this check `if self.request.user.id != self.request.data['author']:`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override `create()` the method of your `TextViewSet`

views.py

```
from rest_framework.response import Response

class TextViewSet(ModelViewSet):      
    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        if request.user.id == request.data['author']:
            self.perform_create(serializer)
            headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
        else:
            return Response("Unauthorized", status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED
```

Comment: Mind that passing an author id N that doesn't exist results in the following error message: "Invalid pk \"N\" - object does not exist.". Setting raise_exception to False () removes it:  `serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)`.

Comment: That's great, glad to know that you fixed it

Answer (score 0):

The real question is why not just set author to the logged in user and not let the client send in any ID at all?

The normal way of doing this is by:

```
class MyViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    ...
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        '''The logged in user is always the author'''
        return serializer.save(author=self.request.user)
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        '''Limit the queryset to the author, i.e the logged in user, for fetching/updating data'''
        return self.queryset.filter(author=self.request.user)
```

But if you really want to send in author-id then you can also use a custom Permission for it to have it re-usable.

```
from rest_framework.permissions import BasePermission

class UserIsAuthor(BasePermission):
    default_author_field = "author"

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        author_field = getattr(
            view,
            "permission_author_field",
            self.default_author_field
        )
        return request.user.is_authenticated and (
            request.user.pk == request.data.get(author_field)
        )
```

used as:

```
class ExampleViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = [UserIsAuthor]
    
    # optional if the default "author" isnt what you want.
    permission_author_field = "some_field_in_request_data"
```