# ListCreateAPIView doesn't return the response

Tags: python, django

I want to return the custom json response after `perform_create`

```
class MyObjList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.request.method == 'GET':
            return MyObjListSerializer
        return MyObjCreateSerializer
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        // do something here. 
        return Response({'isDraft': 1})
class MyObjCreateSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    class Meta:
        fields = ('answer')
```

However this dosen't return the any response,for my Javasctipt

```
axios.post(API_URL, data, config).then(({ data }) => {
  console.log(data); // just show {}
}).catch(error => {
  console.log(error);
});
```

What I want to do is create object in `perform_create` and return the keyname to the client.

However currently in my code it doesn't return anything.

I wonder if Serializer class is relevant, but I am not sure the role of serializer class for POST>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should override the `create()` method instead of `perform_create()` method. Here is explained why: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69395096/8332763

- `perform_create` changes saving logic.
- `create` changes request/response handling

Comment: Thank you using `create` solves my problem.